# how to post the edittext n spinner values to webservice if either one is visible

Tags: android

i got stuck in a critical situation plz sme1 help me in resolve the problem, i have a edittext and a spinner initially they r set invinsible when i select a program depending on the program credentials it will appear either edittext or spinner somehow i managed to post the edittext values to webservice but m unable to post the spinner value. anyone plz help me on this..

Thanx,
Goutham

Answer (score 0):

check visibility of a view with [`getVisibility`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getVisibility%28%29) first. if your spinner is visible, then take the selected value out of it with `Spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()` and post it to your server.